# How to Explode string in mysql and get each value?

Tags: mysql

I have a string like this **67,73,89**. I want to explode all the value and compare each value. In php  I can do it like this

```
<?php
$marks = "67, 73, 89";
$explode = explode(", ",$marks);
foreach($explode as $mark){
    if($mark > 80)
    echo $mark."<br>";
}
?>
```

Can anyone give me the mysql code so that i can select all the student roll number where marks contains atleast one value > 80.
 You can use mysql explode function like this...

```
CREATE FUNCTION explode(str VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), pos INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos-1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

Table structure is

```
╔═════════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║ Roll_No ║ Name  ║  Marks   ║
╠═════════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║       1 ║ John  ║ 67,73,89 ║
║       2 ║ Bob   ║ 75,69,80 ║
║       3 ║ Smith ║ 62,79,92 ║
╚═════════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: does your table have any column which have comma separated value?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do that in MySQL?

Comment: Edited question is more clear, can you show us your table's structure?

Comment: Yes @AlivetoDie

Comment: I just editted my question with a clear example and table structure. @HtmHell

Comment: sample output please

Comment: Then you probably have a bad structure design. You probably want to have another table with many to many relationship.